# Updation using VF PAGE with Custom Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, button

I tried to create the custom controller for contact object and to update contact record by click button (vf page).
My Apex Class:

```
public  class fetchContact {
    public Apexpages.standardcontroller Ctrl; 
    Contact contact1;
    public fetchContact(){
        contact1 = [Select Id,Name,Phone,Email FROM Contact where id = :Ctrl.getid()];
    }
       public  Contact getContact(){

        return contact1;
    }
    public PageReference save(){
       return ctrl.save();
    }
}
```

Vf Page:

```
<apex:page controller="fetchContact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Detail" id="Contact_Detail">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contact}" var="Cont">
            <apex:column >
                <apex.inputfield value = "{!Cont.id}"></apex.inputfield>
                <apex:inputText value="{!Cont.Name}"/>
                  <apex:inputText value="{!Cont.Phone}"/>    
                 <apex:inputField value="{!Cont.Email}"/>
                  </apex:column>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
              <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"></apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I got error " The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator. "
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This page shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong with this code.

Comment: your VF page defines a custom controller yet the controller code you posted references a standard controller;